# Trigger OnChange in TestCafe

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, onchange, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm new to using testcafe and I am trying to test logging into my app. Currently, the testing logic is this

```
    await t
    .typeText('#username', 'user')
    .typeText('#password', 'userpass');
    .click('.btn');
```

This fails because my login component stores the credentials in state variables that are set when OnChange() is triggered on the inputs. How can I trigger an event in testcafe?

I have researched a little on react and found that triggering OnChange for inputs can be done like this

```
    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    Selector('#username').dispatchEvent(event);
```

but I don't know how to correctly import the Event module into a test cafe suite. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi! Usually you do not need to trigger events manually. TestCafe should do it automatically. If some expected event is not raised, it is possible that something went wrong inside TestCafe. Could you please provide us with a page where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: And clarify please what the TestCafe version do you use. The latest version is 0.15.0. If you use an older version please try to run your test with the latest version.

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not do my research on the problem well enough. Basically in my tests the call to log in was failing because the parameters of the call were null (these should be set during the OnChange trigger). So I assumed the OnChange was not getting triggered. After further investigation, the OnChange is being triggered, there is some issue here (probably not with testcafe) but it is not OnChange. Thank you two for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to trigger events manually. TestCafe does this automatically.

The issue is not related to the onChange handler neither TestCafe.

Comment: Maybe with typetext, but not with 'SetFilesToUpload'.